# SQL Model-JDBC Not Showing Up

Tags: java, eclipse, sqlite, jdbc

Hi I have been trying to set up SQlite for the past 4 days now and I have run into an issue with SQL Model-JDBC not showing up. I am using eclipse luna and have been following http://wiki.eclipse.org/Connecting_to_SQLite. I tried installing Derby and dtp and when I right click Database Connections in file explorer, click new, i am supposed to see SQL Model-JDBC, but I do not see it. What did I do wrong? There are like 30 convoluted steps to getting SQlite installed I have followed them the best I can. To recap, SQL Model-JDBC is not showing up in Database Connections. Is there a driver that is missing? maybe the initialization of the EMF or GEF?

Comment: this 30 steps include installing sql server?

Comment: Well I found that in order to install SQlite, I would have to install EMF, GEF, Apache Derby, and DTP. I thank that's all. I Think the issue is with Apache Derby, but I have no idea where to start. It could be an issue with DTP. Basically I need to know what program is responsible for making SQL Model-JDBC show up in the Database-->New

Comment: your linked pages states: "This page was last modified 17:05, 8 November 2006" you're sure its the right way for your version?

Comment: To "install" SQLite, all you need is the SQLite jar file.

Comment: Technically I did put in the jar file into the Eclipse java stuff. I've basically done everything that the Website told me to. I put the SQlite dll file into the java library, and directed eclipse to the sqlite jar file in the downloaded zip files. Would firefox sqlite manager just be better? I am looking at that, and it seems like if I went with using the firefox sqlite manager I would have saved time by not going through all this crap. I just thought installing directly into eclipse would be better but I guess not. Would the manager be better?